# Display a Sequence in a Console in C#

Tags: c#, .net, console, sequence

How can I display an output that looks more like this

> Goal: < 1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 1 >
>
> NOT like: < 1, 2, 1 , 2, 1, > // there is a comma at the end
>
> Currently it displays: 1 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 2 ,  1 ,

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
 {
    int coin1 = RandomFlip(); //1 head 2 tails
    int coin2 = RandomFlip();
      
     if(coin1 == coin2)
      {
       Console.Write(coin1 + ", ")
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't know which iteration is the last loop you'll have to build up a list of results and then display it later.

```
var flipValues = List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
   int coin1 = RandomFlip(); //1 head 2 tails
   int coin2 = RandomFlip();
   if(coin1 == coin2)
   {
       flipValues.Add(coin1);
   }
}

Console.Write(string.Join(", ", flipValues.Select(f => f.ToString());
```

Comment: Think the problem with this is that you don't know when the last comma will show up. It only writes the number if both coin1 and coin2 are equal. So it might only be true on the first loop which will mean a comma will show up at the end.

Comment: @shf301 the comma still shows up at the end. I followed your instructions and the output was 1,2,1,1,2, . My  goal is is to have the program looking like this < 1 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 2  > no comma after the 2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to hold onto your results until you know you're finished, then print them once you have the entire list. Here's one way of doing that:

```
List<int> results = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    int coin1 = RandomFlip(); //1 head 2 tails
    int coin2 = RandomFlip();

    if(coin1 == coin2)
    {
        results.Add(coin1);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results.Select(ToString));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var res = String.Join(", ", 
    Enumerable.Range(1, 7)
    .Select(n => 
    {
        int coin1 = RandomFlip(); //1 head 2 tails
        int coin2 = RandomFlip();

        return new { coin1, coin2 };
    })
    .Where(c => c.coin1 == c.coin2)
    .Select(c => c.coin1)
);
Console.Write(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    int coin1 = RandomFlip();
    int coin2 = RandomFlip();
    if (coin1 == coin2)
    {
        numbers.Add(coin1);
    }
}
string output = "";
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
{
    output+=numbers[i].ToString();
    if (i < numbers.Count-1)
    {
        output+=", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: So, looks like everyone's got the same idea, awks. Didn't know this "string.Join" existed. Will be using it in the future ^_^

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is keep an output string you append to, add the comma before adding the coin1 output. You just need to make sure not to add a comma to the string if there's nothing in there yet.

```
string output = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    int coin1 = RandomFlip(); //1 head 2 tails
    int coin2 = RandomFlip();

    if (coin1 == coin2)
    {
        if (output != "")
            output += ", ";
        output += coin1;
    }
}
Console.Write(output);
```